# Does it make sense to use Cordova or PhoneGap for the development of a pure browser-based web application?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, mobile

At first glimpse Cordova and PhoneGap exist primarily for the use to develop apps to be used on a mobile device. Well, I am not interessted in the developement of native mobile apps.

There exists a webapplication (a cms) of our own and the question is now if a mobile toolkit like Cordova or PhoneGap is able to be of any help to develop parts of our cms functionalities with it in order to be able to support more plattforms.

**Does it make sense to use Cordova or PhoneGap for the developement of a pure browser-based web application?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phonegap (or Cordova as its now called) works by wrapping your webpages in a `Webview` and giving you access (in JavaScript) to some of the native device functions, such as the Camera, Accelerometer, Contacts etc.

As for whether it will help you depends on if want to make use of any of the native device functions, for example if you think incorporating the Camera (current HTML support for camera is quite spotty) into your web app is of use then you probably should consider it.

Another consideration is how your users will access the applications, with Phonegap it gets packages into a native app and  they can just launch it from their home-screen (or however they launch apps on their mobile device), while with a Web App it depends on the device, on iOS you can pin it to your home screen and add some meta tags to make it appear more native like (for example hide the address bar) while on Android as far as I know you can't do that.

Finally consider that with Phonegap it might be more of a pain to debug your application since your HTML/Js is wrapped in a `Webview`, but as far as I've seen there is no easy way to debug it there.

One other thing I seem to recall reading somewhere that on iOS Apple doesn't give your native applications' Webviews access to the same amount of memory as if it were in safari so the exact sane web application when packaged into a Phonegap application might actually be slower.

To sum up, the benefits of wrapping your application in a Phonegap wrapper are access to native device functions and how your users access your app, if those aren't important (or the cons outweigh the benefits) than it probably isn't worth your while to go that route.

Answer (score 2):

Cordova/Phonegap extend javascript with functionality provided by mobile operating systems. Therefore apps developed with these frameworks must be compiled to the target platform and only embed the HTML etc. in an embedded browser. The extensions need java, objective-c etc. code to run so I don't think that you are able to benefit from this code.

You are forced to write your own mobile device compliant HTML code when using Cordova/Phonegap. There are no neat mobile device ready user interface controls provided by the framework but only access to device specific hardware or software apis like notification etc. is given.

Answer (score 1):

Cordova is just the latest name of PhoneGap. I would not go for that if you just want to build a mobile website. First of all publishing such an app on several online stores (iTunes, Play) is a pain.